# Why am I getting a copy instead of a reference when flattening a list of ndarrays?

Tags: python, list, reference, copy, numpy-ndarray

And how do I get references to each element in the `ndarrays`?

The goal is to take a `list` of variable shaped `ndarrays` containing primitives, use `ravel()` on all the `ndarrays` and merge them into a `list` who elements are all references to the elements in the `list` of `ndarrays`.

Here is my attempt at this. To be clear, `weights` is a `list` of `ndarrays`, and I want `weights_unraveled` to be a one dimensional `list` containing references to every element in each `ndarray`.

```
def unravel_weights(weights):
    weights_unraveled = []
    for w in weights:
        weights_unraveled.extend(w.ravel())
    return weights_unraveled
```

I know that `w.ravel()` returns a one dimensional `list` with references to elements of `w` and assigning it to another variable does not make a copy. I have tested it. Does passing the value to a function make a copy? Does the returning of a value from a function make a copy? I doubt it because assignment did not.

If `extend()` is making copies, how do I stop it, or how do I merge the `list` of references returned by `w.ravel()` into a single `list` containing references to every element in each `ndarray`?

This is the code that manifests the undesired behavior.

```
    flat_child_weights = unravel_weights(child_weights)
    flat_parent_weights = unravel_weights(weights1) 
    for i in range(len(flat_child_weights)):
        change = random.choice([True, False])
        if change:
            flat_child_weights[i] = flat_parent_weights[i]
```

Is a copy being made when assigning the return value of `unravel_weights`? I also doubt it.

Debugging has verified that `flat_child_weights` and `flat_parent_weights` are indeed one dimensional `lists`, but they are copies of `child_weights` and `weights1` respectively. To be clear, `flat_child_weights[i] = flat_parent_weights[i]` does change the elements of `flat_child_weights`, but the changes are not reflected in `child_weights`.

How can I get the elements of `child_weights` to reflect changes in `flat_child_weights`?

Answer (score 0):

You get references instead of copies from your `numpy` calls because they return views and not copies, unlike the `array.extend`. Here is a method that will do the same, though it requires some upfront work. You deleted your old question, so I cannot reference that code.

If I recall, you started with a list of `ndarray`s, which could not be directly turned into a 2D ndarray because the `ndarray`s are different lengths. This will replace your `unravel_weights`.

1. Create a 1D `ndarray` with all the weights flattened:

```
flat_child_weights = np.concatenate([weights.ravel() for weights in child_weights)
```

2. Key step to link your output to the work on the flattened weights: recreate `child_weights` from *views* of `flat_child_weights`, something like:

```
child_weights_new = []
index = 0
for weights in child_weights:
    child_weights_new.append(flat_child_weights[index:index+weights.size()].reshape(weights.shape))
    index += weights.size()
```

Now you can run through your work on the `flat_child_weights`, and `child_weights_new` will be updated (but not `child_weights`), so return `child_weights_new`.

Comment: Yea, the old question was a mess and I got some stuff wrong.

Comment: ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

Comment: Where are you getting this error, on `np.concatenate`? If so, is `child_weights` a list of 1D `ndarray`s?

Comment: It is from ```np.concatenate```. child_weights a list of variable shaped ndarrays.

Comment: Ah, important detail. I've made some slight changes to handle arbitrary input shape and maintain that shape in the output `child_weights_new`.